# React Native Navigation titleImage

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using react  native navigation and I have titleImage set.That image scales correctly on my iOS 6Plus but I have a friend who has the same phone but does not scale correctly. The image tries to come below the line of the title and cover up some of the components below.Does anyone have the same issue?

Thanks

Comment: This is not nearly enough information. You need to add more, at least some code. Ideally a reproducible simple demo on snack.expo.io.

Comment: Here is the code. It is declarative to get tab navigation. 
  import iosImageLabel from '../../assets/images/Squ-TypeOnly-color.jpg';
  
  Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
        tabs: [
          {
            screen: 'xx.UserScreen',
            label: 'Activity'
            titleImage: iosImageLabel,
            icon: activity
          }
 ]
});

Comment: check whether dpi are same